# Icons element with xml-file

Tags: xml

I'm trying to put glyphicon with xml-file, because the menu I have used is xml-file.

```
<root>
  <item>
    <text>Home</text>
    <icon><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></icon>
  </item>

  <item>
    <text>About</text>    
  </item>
</root>
```

Comment: Absolutely no idea of what you're asking.

Comment: The menu is developed in a xml file, i want to put an icon in the menu but i cant make it work

Comment: What menu? We have no idea of your CONTEXT here.